# She did nothing except that she complained

Tags: conjunctions, definition, optional-that

> **BUT** (conjunction)
>
> except: *She did nothing **but** complain* (= *She did nothing except
> that she complained*).
>
> https://www.wordreference.com/definition/but

[Is the paraphrase given adequate in modern English](https://oed.com/oed2/00079534)?

Comment: No, it isn't. The original sentence communicates that all she did was complain.

Comment: @FeliniusRex what are the differences in meaning between the example and its  paraphrase ?

Comment: **Nothing but....** is idiomatic. **Except that...** is not. That's why native speakers read your paraphrase as the person was lazy and complained, whereas my paraphrase and the original both mean that the person was complaining and that's all she did.

Comment: "nothing but" = "nothing other than". "Nothing except that" is unnatural, and it's not clear to me what it means. I'd have to guess it means "nothing but". Are you asking about the meaning of "nothing but" or about "nothing except that"?